# Unity 2D Game Kit image changed to warm color?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, gamekit

Why color of image in sprites map changed to warm color like this. How I can turn it off. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that Tilemap Renderer setting to custom material. I just change it to sprites-default.

Comment: That is good Rico. The option I gave you may work for other conditions, in case you want to change the effect of the tiles without editing the images. But if your answer is what you were looking for, accept your own answer so it appears as solved

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the ambient light of the scene. you can read about this in the following tutorial.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/ambient-lighting

You can add somewhere in your code:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Example() {
        RenderSettings.ambientLight = //here the color you consider
    }
}
```